# Landscape and Portrait in same pdf

Tags: c#, evopdf, evo

I need to generate a pdf report from a URL in our application. Is it possible to have both Landscape and Portrait pages in the same pdf document that is generated?

I'd like to have the bar charts as Portrait, and the Tables as Landscape (horizontal). Looking at the EVO doc's I don't know if this is possible.

I know that you can define either Landscape or Portrait with

```
htmlToPdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfPageOrientation
```

But this is applied to the whole document. I'd like something I could potentially define the html that would tell EVO to print this section as Landscape.

Answer (score 0):

You can have Portrait and Landscape section in the same PDF. For this you can create a blank Document object and add a PDF page with the desired orientation to this document. On the newly created PDF page you can add a HtmlToPdfElement object to render the HTML and automatically add PDF pages with the same orientation with the PDF page you initially created. The procedure can be repeated with  PDF pages of different orientations. There is a live sample with C# code for this approach in [Merge Multiple HTML Pages into a Single PDF](http://www.evopdf.com/demo/HTML_to_PDF/Merge_Multiple_HTML.aspx) demo. The code sample is also copied below:

```
protected void convertToPdfButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create the PDF document where to add the HTML documents
    Document pdfDocument = new Document();

    // Create a PDF page where to add the first HTML
    PdfPage firstPdfPage = pdfDocument.AddPage();

    try
    {
        // Create the first HTML to PDF element
        HtmlToPdfElement firstHtml = new HtmlToPdfElement(0, 0, firstUrlTextBox.Text);

        // Optionally set a delay before conversion to allow asynchonous scripts to finish
        firstHtml.ConversionDelay = 2;

        // Add the first HTML to PDF document
        AddElementResult firstAddResult = firstPdfPage.AddElement(firstHtml);

        PdfPage secondPdfPage = null;
        PointF secondHtmlLocation = Point.Empty;

        if (startNewPageCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            // Create a PDF page where to add the second HTML
            secondPdfPage = pdfDocument.AddPage();
            secondHtmlLocation = PointF.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            // Add the second HTML on the PDF page where the first HTML ended
            secondPdfPage = firstAddResult.EndPdfPage;
            secondHtmlLocation = new PointF(firstAddResult.EndPageBounds.Left, firstAddResult.EndPageBounds.Bottom);
        }

        // Create the second HTML to PDF element
        HtmlToPdfElement secondHtml = new HtmlToPdfElement(secondHtmlLocation.X, secondHtmlLocation.Y, secondUrlTextBox.Text);

        // Optionally set a delay before conversion to allow asynchonous scripts to finish
        secondHtml.ConversionDelay = 2;

        // Add the second HTML to PDF document
        secondPdfPage.AddElement(secondHtml);

        // Save the PDF document in a memory buffer
        byte[] outPdfBuffer = pdfDocument.Save();

        // Send the PDF as response to browser

        // Set response content type
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");

        // Instruct the browser to open the PDF file as an attachment or inline
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename=Merge_Multipe_HTML.pdf; size={0}", outPdfBuffer.Length.ToString()));

        // Write the PDF document buffer to HTTP response
        Response.BinaryWrite(outPdfBuffer);

        // End the HTTP response and stop the current page processing
        Response.End();
    }
    finally
    {
        // Close the PDF document
        pdfDocument.Close();
    }
}
```